# Как правильно пользоваться Nullable ссылочными типами?

Tags: c#, .net

Включаю я значит их в проекте и все засыпано предупреждениями...

Хотя в некоторых местах я не хочу проверять nullable ссылочные типы перед использованием, так как если упадет, то упадет, значит я этого не ожидал.

Или в DTO моделях с публичными свойствами. По бизнес логике они не должны принимать значения null, но одновременно я их присвоить через конструктор не могу => в одном блоке я заполняю одни поля, а в другом другие.

Как с ними правильно работать?

Answer (score 4):

Смотрите.

По поводу того, где проверять на `null`. Правильная стратегия — определить границы ваших модулей. Внутри модуля вы доверяете nullable-аннотации, точно так же как вы и не делаете других проверок аргументов функций. Однако публичные функции, которые могут вызвать из-за границы модуля, не имеют права рассчитывать, что вызывающий код «хороший», и должны проверять свои аргументы на входе. Компилятор, кстати, выдаёт предупреждения если вы не следуете этой стратегии.

По поводу DTO-объектов, Майкрософт на текущий момент [предлагает три опции](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-migration-strategies#late-initialized-properties-data-transfer-objects-and-nullability) ([альтернативная ссылка](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/nullable-migration-strategies#late-initialized-properties-data-transfer-objects-and-nullability), если вам нравится читать в переводе):

- Инициализировать в конструкторе (то есть, отойти от чистого DTO); или
- Отказаться от автоматических свойств, и бросать `InvalidOperationException` в геттере, если обнаружится `null`; или
- Заткнуть анализатор, инициализируя свойства конструкцией `null!` (означающей «да, это `null`, заткнись, я знаю, что делаю»).

Кстати, использование инициализирующих функций в конструкторе вполне позволительно, необходимо только правильно проставить атрибут `[MemberNotNull]`.

Comment: По конкретным проблемам по идее стоит спрашивать отдельно. Может быть, даже тег для этого придумать.

Comment: А еще момент, когда есть предупреждение, что я в конструкторе принимаю НЕ nullable string, а мне говорят "Ты дурак, зачем ты проверяешь не nullable reference тип на null, так как проверка будет всегда отрицательной"... По идее, ничего не мешает передать в такой конструктор null и компилятор будет просто предупреждать или вообще вырубить в каком-то проекте nullable фичу и передавать null'ы ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @iluxa1810: Если ваш класс публичный, и конструктор публичный, то его вполне могут вызвать с `null`, так что проверка обязательна. Это совершенно аналогично любым публичным функциям, доступным снаружи модуля.

Comment: Это да, но не понимаю, почему у меня выдавалось предупреждение на проверку входных строк в конструкторе "Дурак, у тебя не нуллабл строка, зачем ты ее проверяешь?"

Comment: @iluxa1810: а можно скриншот? или текст ошибки, и код конструктора?